how to pass a gbm memory directly to OpenCL kernel function
I have a camera driver (for Linux) which can write the raw data directly into gbm gpu memory by specifying the fd (fd is obtained using gbm_bo_create & gbm_bo_get_fd).
And I want my OpenCL kernel function directly access this gbm, but not create a mmap of this gbm, and then using enqueueWriteBuffer to copy from this mmap pointer. Is there any way I can do so?
Or alternatively, how can I get a mmap fd of this GPU memory owned by cl::Buffer, so that the camera driver can directly write the data into it?
Thanks!
